# Swagger - Springfox always generates some response messages (401,403...) by default. How can I remove them?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I have controller as simple as this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/async/data", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ApiOperation(value = "Gets data", notes="Gets data asynchronously")
@ApiResponses(value={@ApiResponse(code=200, message="OK")})
public Callable<List<Data>> getData(){
    return ( () -> {return dataService.loadData();} );
}
```

I was expecting to have only a response message for HTTP status 200. However springfox always generates the ones below (401, 403, 404). How can I disable (not show) them?

```
async-rest-controller Show/Hide List Operations Expand Operations
GET /async/data Gets data

Implementation Notes
Gets data asynchronously

Response Class (Status 200)
ModelModel Schema
{}

Response Content Type 

Response Messages
HTTP Status Code    Reason  Response Model  Headers
401 Unauthorized        
403 Forbidden       
404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should be able to set up the plugin to ***not*** use the default response messages. Follow below instructions for different versions.

For 1.0.2 or prior

```java
  new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(...)
        //More config
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false) //<-- this should be false
  ...;
```

For 2.x

```java
  new Docket()
        //More config
        .useDefaultResponseMessages(false) //<-- this should be false
  ...;
```

Comment: This does remove the undocumented response codes, But doesn't remove 200 code

Comment: @warrior107 : if you use 2.x and a recent version of spring, add this annotation on your controller endpoint:     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
Or whatever response code it should return. In swagger 2.x, 200 should not be in the list at the bottom, only at the top of each endpoint's descritpion: "Response class (Status XXX)"

Comment: This approach removes all the default responses for all the resources. Is there a way to remove a particular default response, 201, from a particular POST endpoint?

Answer (score 5):

With OpenAPI 3, you just need to add this property to the applications.yml (or similar)

```yaml
springdoc:
  override-with-generic-response: false
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution in springdoc and found yours. But this doesn't work. Adding this in properties file brings no change. Can you refer me the doc where you find this?

Comment: It works with default `400 Bad Request` and `200 OK` responses! I'm working with the latest OpenAPI version at this moment designed as a dependency for Java (2.1.0) + Spring Boot 3.x. With that property it hides/eliminates all not documented endpoints.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using

```
new Docket().useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
```

you may also need to use this annotation depending on the status code you want to return:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

⚠️ Don't use `ResponseEntity` with WebFlux as that will always add the 200 code. See this [github issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/908).