# useDefaultResponseMessages(false) not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I'm using the swagger-codegen to create a spring-server.

I also used the `.useDefaultResponseMessages(false)`-attribute 
as described in [Swagger - Springfox always generates some response messages (401,403...) by default. How can I remove them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047129/swagger-springfox-always-generates-some-response-messages-401-403-by-defa/30065563#30065563)

SwaggerConfig.java:

```
public Docket customImplementation() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
    .select()
    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myrest.api"))
    .build()
    .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
    .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
    .apiInfo(apiInfo());}
```

related apipart: Api.java:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "Returns all clouds from the system that the user has access to ", response = Cloud.class, responseContainer = "List", tags = {
      "cloud",})
  @ApiResponses(value = {
      @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "All clouds ", response = Cloud.class),
        /*@ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Authorization for this action is missing", response = Error.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden action", response = Error.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "An unexpected Error occured", response = Error.class),*/
      @ApiResponse(code = 504, message = "Server temporary not available", response = Error.class)})

  @RequestMapping(value = "/clouds",
      produces = {"application/json"},
      method = RequestMethod.GET)
  ResponseEntity<List<Cloud>> findClouds();
```

But the swagger-ui still looks like:
[swagger-ui: ResponseMessageTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGGiK.png)

So it seems `.useDefaultResponseMessages(false)` is not working.

How do I disable these default error responses?

---

@John Duskin

I changes the Docketinitialization,changed the `@Controller` to `@Restcontroller` but I still get the 404 Message by `Get`

[different looking 404-Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQa08.png)

The generated Serverstubs from Swagger-Codegen looks like:

Api.java:

```
@Api(value = "clouds", description = "the clouds API")
public interface CloudsApi {

@ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "Returns all clouds from the system that the user has access to ", response = Cloud.class, responseContainer = "List", tags={ "cloud", })
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "All clouds ", response = Cloud.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Authorization for this action is missing", response = Cloud.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden action", response = Cloud.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "An unexpected Error occured", response = Cloud.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 504, message = "Server temporary not available", response = Cloud.class) })

@RequestMapping(value = "/clouds",
        produces = { "application/json" },
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<List<Cloud>> findClouds();
```

and the separated Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CloudsApiController implements CloudsApi {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@Autowired
private CloudService cloudService;

public ResponseEntity<List<Cloud>> findClouds() {
//do some magic
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Cloud>>(cloudList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
[...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the problem beside working ...

this was a Spring Annotation Problem.
In  my SwaggerDocumentationConfig.java I added `@EnableSwagger2` and everything works as wanted

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerDocumentationConfig {

@Bean
public Docket customImplementation(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myrest.api"))
                .build()
            .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
            .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the call to useDefaultResponseMessages after the build method in the Docket.  I've updated your code to show what I mean.

Hope that helps.

```
public Docket customImplementation() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("myrest.api"))
      .build()
      .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
      .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
      .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
      .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

To get the calls working on my machine I've put the ApiReponses with the Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my_model")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Rocks fell, everyone died.") })
```

**Update**

Are you putting the description on the method?

Here is what I have working on my project. Note the API Responses are attached to the controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my_model/gogo")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
@ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Rocks Fall") })
public class GoGoClass {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ApiOperation(value = "Description")
public void run(
        @ApiParam(value = "Param1 description") @RequestParam(required = true) final String param1,
        @ApiParam(value = "Param 2 description")  final String param2)
        throws ModelException {
        // Do stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: I've done an update to my post. If you would like to try that. I hope it helps.