# Swagger UI - Response code

Tags: spring, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am quite new with Swagger and I am a little bit confused with the response codes given back.

I wrote a code with th purpose that it should drop an error message with the response code 500.

If I let my code run, then the method gives a 200 - ok status, although in the header is my error code visible. But in Swagger, it is only to see when I click on the "Try it" button...

See pictures below...:

[image]

[image]

Is it a normal behavior? I wish to see only my error code given back, not the OK message and status... Is it possible?

Here is a short snippet from my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/pong")
@Produces(UTF8MediaType.UTF8_APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Check whether Error handler works or nottttttttttt", response = String.class)
public String pong() throws GeneralError {
    throw new GeneralError(httpServletRequest);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public Response toResponse(final Throwable throwable) {
    GeneralError generalError;

    try {
        generalError = (GeneralError) throwable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        generalError = new GeneralError(throwable);
    }

    String json = JacksonMapper.prettyPrint(generalError);

    return Response
            .status(generalError.getHttpStatus())
            .type(UTF8MediaType.UTF8_APPLICATION_JSON)
            .entity(json)
            .build();
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Is this Springfox? You are probably missing the `@ApiResponses` annotation.

Comment: @Helen thank you, but I mean to show ONLY the ApiResponse answer...Is there a way to hide the "200 successful operation" content?

Comment: Does [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30047129/113116) help?